# Remove an item from array by id

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
    data: function(){
            return {
            items: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Item 1', bool: false},
            { id: '2', name: 'Item 2', bool: false},
            { id: '3', name: 'Item 3', bool: false},
            { id: '4', name: 'Item 4', bool: false}
            ],
            checkedItems: [],
        };
    },

    methods: 
    {
        select: function(event, index) {
            if (!this.items[index].bool) {                    
                this.checkedItems.splice(index, 1);
            } else { 
                this.checkedItems.push(this.items[index]);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on the `div` it copies the items data into `checkedItems` and sets `bool` to `true`.

Is it possible to target the item id and remove that specific one from `checkedItems` as the current splice is removing the wrong item based off the index.

Comment: I'm not sure how your `select` method is invoked, but I guess once you get the id value you can loop over `items`, find the desired entry by matching the id values and then splicing the array

Comment: please provide your full component implementation, especially `template` and `script`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an object instead of an array, something like this:

```
data: function(){
            return {
            items: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Item 1', bool: false},
            { id: '2', name: 'Item 2', bool: false},
            { id: '3', name: 'Item 3', bool: false},
            { id: '4', name: 'Item 4', bool: false}
            ],
            checkedItemsObj: {},

        };
    },

    methods: 
    {
        select: function(event, index) {
            let item = this.items[index];

            if (!item.bool) {                    
                this.checkedItemsObj[item.id] = item 
            } else { 
                delete this.checkedItemsObj[item.id]  
            }
        },

        getCheckedItems: () => Object.values(data().checkedItemsObj)
    }
```

Now to get the array of checked items anytime, you can call `methods.getCheckedItems()`